# metabase path in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, metabase

I am working on creating virtual directories for a website through a programmatic way. I couldn't get the concept of metabase- what is metabase path and need of it in IIS. 
thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MetaBase *is* IIS.  It holds every configurable element of IIS and is stored in XML form, it is in the windows folder (i.e. \windows\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml).

You can amend this file manually or programmatically but special care should be taken when doing so.

More can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIS_Metabase.

Comment: You also need to allow IIS to take live metabase edits or you will need to restart IIS each time to update the config.